# Cannot delete a file - permission denied - why?

Tags: permissions, files, rm

```
[db2inst1][testing ~/sqllib/db2dump] rm db2diag.log 
rm: cannot remove `db2diag.log': Permission denied
[db2inst1][testing ~/sqllib/db2dump] id
uid=1002(db2inst1) gid=107(db2iadm1) groups=16(dialout),33(video),107(db2iadm1),108(db2fadm1),1001(eduserver)
[db2inst1][testing ~/sqllib/db2dump] ll
total 1381172
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root db2iadm1 1412931954 Oct  2 10:24 db2diag.log
```

Currently logged user (db2inst1) is part of db2iadm1 group that has w permission to the file I want to delete. But I am not able. Any idea why?

### update - permission for parent directory

drwxr-sr-x 2 root     db2iadm1  4096 Aug 22 14:39 db2dump

Comment: What are the permissions on the parent directory? See [Why can `rm` remove read-only files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48579/22651)

Comment: Similar to question: [Why can't I delete this file as root?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206594/why-cant-i-delete-this-file-as-root) .
Suggestion: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206595/92974

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In order to delete a file, you must have write permissions on the directory that the file resides in. When you `rm` a file it makes the `unlink` system call which removes the name from the directory. This only deletes the file if it is the last remaining link to the inode.

You can find more information in [unlink(2)](http://manpages.debian.net/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=unlink&apropos=0&sektion=2&manpath=Debian+6.0+squeeze&format=html&locale=en).