sudo results in a new session with a new controlling PTY
On Linux Ubuntu when at terminal I run sudo su or sudo su - the system creates a new session with a new controlling pts, namely
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 5.15.0-124-generic #134-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 27 20:20:17 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 143254 pts/0    00:00:00 bash
 143302 pts/0    00:00:00 ps
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo su -
root@ubuntu:~# 
root@ubuntu:~# ps
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
 143304 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo
 143305 pts/1    00:00:00 su
 143306 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
 143316 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
root@ubuntu:~#

Is it an expected behavior?
As requested in the comments:
$ ps     
PID TTY          TIME CMD  
146202 pts/0    00:00:00 bash  
146231 pts/0    00:00:00 ps 

$ sudo -s 
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# ps
PID TTY          TIME CMD  
146233 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo  
146234 pts/1    00:00:00 bash  
146240 pts/1    00:00:00 ps 


Not an answer, but: Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?

Do you really need to run sudo su when sudo -s will do. And if you do use simply sudo -s do you get the new pty?

Also, what is the output of sudo -l?

@ChrisDavies I can reproduce this on my Arch and all of sudo -i, sudo -s, sudo su and sudo su - produce the effect the OP describes (pts increased by one in the new shell) while simple su or su - do not. So it looks like a sudo thing.

@ChrisDavies
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ps     PID TTY          TIME CMD  146202 pts/0    00:00:00 bash  146231 pts/0    00:00:00 ps ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -s root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#  root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# ps     PID TTY          TIME CMD  146233 pts/1    00:00:00 sudo  146234 pts/1    00:00:00 bash  146240 pts/1    00:00:00 ps root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# 
`

@muru
`ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for ubuntu on ubuntu:
env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin, use_pty
User ubuntu may run the following commands on ubuntu:
(ALL : ALL) ALL
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$  `

Please add information to your question. Not to comments, which can be deleted at zero notice

From man sudoers for Ubuntu 22.04:
 use_pty           If set, and sudo is running in a terminal, the command will be run in a
                   pseudo-terminal (even if no I/O logging is being done).  If the sudo
                   process is not attached to a terminal, use_pty has no effect.

                   A malicious program run under sudo may be capable of injecting commands
                   into the user's terminal or running a background process that retains
                   access to the user's terminal device even after the main program has
                   finished executing.  By running the command in a separate pseudo-terminal,
                   this attack is no longer possible.  This flag is off by default.

Though it says this is disabled by default, it became enabled by default in sudo 1.9.14, and it seems this configuration change was backported to the version in Ubuntu 22.04 (or rather in some release between 20.04 and 22.04). Checking the package changelog, this was done to address a CVE:
sudo (1.9.6-1~exp2) experimental; urgency=low

  [ Marc Haber ]
  * add use_pty to default configuration, fixing CVE-2005-4890.
    Thanks to Daniel Kahn Gillmor (Closes: #657784)

The Debian bug report mentioned here that resulted in this change upstream from Ubuntu is https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=657784: 'CVE-2005-4890: tty hijacking possible in "sudo" via TIOCSTI ioctl'. So now there is a documentation bug in the manpage regarding the default status.

Thanks, I commented out Defaults   use_pty in /etc/sudoers and it works as expected !

Btw, /etc/sudoers has permissions
root@ubuntu:~# ll /etc/sudoers -r--r----- 1 root root 1672 Oct 25 19:27 /etc/sudoers 
, yet root user is able to write/modify it -- e.g. using visudo. Has root access to any file/directory in the system ?

@CarloC in most situations, yes: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/412247/70524

Ah ok...so here the relevant capability of root is CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE, right ?

That's correct.
