# What does "execute" permission mean on a folder?

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

I have read [this topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61570/what-does-it-mean-if-a-directory-has-only-x-executable-permission-for-certain), which gave me some info but I feel I am not fully getting it. What does the execute permission actually mean on a folder? I fully understand what it means on a file, but on a folder.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

With the execute bit set you have the permission

1. to `cd` into the directory
2. Also for long listing `ls -l` i.e. to view the meta data of the files inside the directory (Provided that `read` permission is there for the directory.

Comment: Thanks. I know english is not my native language but even now, for me it is not that obvious that the doc means `cd` (and `ls -l`) are allowed, especially `cd` actually. 
But anyway, thanks a lot for the clarification then. `+x` permission on a folder means I can `cd` it. excellent!

Comment: @UlrichDangel very correct, I've edited my answer.