# rm prompt when deleting unwritable files

Tags: rm, gnu

This is about GNU `rm`. The info page says:

> Otherwise, if a file is unwritable, standard input is a terminal, and the `-f` or `--force` option is not given, or the `-i` or `--interactive=always` option is given, `rm` prompts the user for whether to remove the file. If the response is not affirmative, the file is skipped.

- Is this GNU only?
- When using `rm` as root this does not happen on my system. Is this normal behavior? I can't find it documented anywhere.
- What's the rationale for this behavior? It only increases the confusion of users, who tend to think that you need to have write permissions for a file to delete it. It makes them think that `rm` chmods the file. But `rm` can also delete the file if one isn't the owner.

Comment: You say "this does not happen on my system", but you don't provide details about your system or your version of `rm`.

Comment: you don't need write permission on a file in order to delete it - you need write permission on the directory that contains the file.  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files

Comment: @Ryan: GNU coreutils 8.23 on Debian 8.3 with Linux kernel 3.16.0-4-amd64.

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect the new info about the coreutils version. You say "this does not happen". Could I trouble you to clarify what "this" means in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you asked three separate questions, I'll answer them separately.

Your first question:

> Is this GNU only?

I'm not sure that it's GNU *only*.  It seems to be a feature of GNU Coreutils' `rm` that is also found in at least some other `rm` documentation.  For example, according to some [old documentation at opengroup.org](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html) for POSIX `rm`:

> 3. If file is not of type directory, the -f option is not specified, and
>      either the permissions of file do not permit writing and the standard
>      input is a terminal or the -i option is specified, rm shall write a
>      prompt to the standard error and read a line from the standard input.
>      If the response is not affirmative, rm shall do nothing more with the
>      current file and go on to any remaining files.

Sound familiar?  It's worded pretty closely to the GNU `rm` documentation you mentioned in your question.

---

Your second question:

> When using rm as root this does not happen on my system. Is this
>   normal behavior? I can't find it documented anywhere.

If you mean that running `rm` with no flags as root does not prompt you when trying to remove an "unwritable file", then yes, this is normal behavior for GNU Coreutils 8.23 (and probably almost every other version of GNU Coreutils).  There doesn't seem to be any documentation for it, but if you dig into [the source for `rm`](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/v8.23/src/rm.c) (you've gotta bounce between several files to piece it all together), it shows that running `rm somefile` from a terminal as the root user will remove `somefile` without a prompt, [even if it's write protected](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1013171).

---

Your third question:

> What's the rationale for this behavior? It only increases the
>   confusion of users, who tend to think that you need to have write
>   permissions for a file to delete it. It makes them think that rm
>   chmods the file. But rm can also delete the file if one isn't the
>   owner.

If you mean why can a user delete a write-protected file that they do not own, that behavior has less to do with `rm` and more to do with filesystem permissions.  See [linuxdevcenter.com](http://www.linuxdevcenter.com/cmd/cmd.csp?path=r/rm), [cyberciti.biz](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-delete-remove-file/), and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Rm_(Unix)&oldid=689924233#Permissions), which collectively state (more or less):

> Usually, on most filesystems, deleting a file requires write
>   permission on the parent directory (and execute permission, in order
>   to enter the directory in the first place), but you need not have
>   permission on the file itself.  **Note that, confusingly for beginners,
>   permissions on the file itself are irrelevant.** However, GNU rm asks
>   for confirmation if a write-protected file is to be deleted, unless
>   the -f option is used.

The bold emphasis is mine.  This is how Linux and other Unix-like OSes handle file deletions based on file permissions.

Answer (score 2):

## plain user

You might wish to protect a file from your own deletion/modification. A quick way is to `chmod 000 foo` (or `chmod -w foo`). However, this is of no use if **you** choose to delete it unwillingly.

So `rm` command will inform you (as non root), if this is the case, that's why there is a confirmation request.

## root

when running as root, an specially during batch/automatic procedures,

1. you are supposed to know what you are doing.
2. many shell might hang if confirmation is asked.

as a consequence, file are deleted "on sight".

## confirmation

confirmation can be request (`-i`) or turn off (`-f`)

- `-i` is default for plain user.
- `-f` is default for root.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this GNU only?

No. This `rm` behavior dates back around 40 years and has been [standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html).

> What's the rationale for this behavior?

From the [1st edition man page for rm](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V1/man/man1/rm.1):

> Removal of a file requires write
>   permission in its directory, but neither read nor write
>   permission on the file itself.
>   
>   
>   BUGS
>   
>   rm probably should ask whether a read--only file is really to be removed.

The implication, I think, is that if a user wanted to protect a file against accidental writing by changing its mode to be read-only, then it was worth making an attempt to protect it from accidental deletion.

The TUHS archive is missing the 2nd edition man pages and rm source, but the [3rd edition man page for rm](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V3/man/man1/rm.1) shows this had been addressed:

> If there is no write permission to a
>   file designated to be removed,
>   rm will print the file name, its mode and then
>   read a line from the standard input.
>   If the line begins with 'y', the file is removed,
>   otherwise it is not.
>   The optional argument -f prevents the above interaction.

Unix and most of its commands eventually got [standardized](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604499/utilities/rm.html), and that's why rm behaves this way today.

> When using rm as root this does not happen on my system. Is this normal behavior?

Not at first, but it is normal behavior now.

The earliest source code I can find is from [V5](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s2/rm.c):

```
    if(getuid() == buf->uid)
        b = 0200; else
        b = 2;
    if((buf->mode & b) == 0)    {
        printf("%s: %o mode ", arg, buf->mode);
        i = b = getchar();
        i = b;
        while(b != '\n' && b != '\0')
            b = getchar();
        if(i != 'y')
            return;
    }
```

which shows the writability check looks at the *write permission by owner* flag if the user running rm owns the file, otherwise *the write permission by others* flag.

In [V7](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/src/cmd/rm.c), rm was changed to use the newly-added [access](http://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/man/man2/access.2) system call:

```
    if (access(arg, 02)<0) {
        printf("rm: %s %o mode ", arg, buf.st_mode&0777);
        if(!yes())
            return;
    }
```

Since `access` considers root to have write access to any file (unless it's on a read-only filesystem), `rm` will typically not ask for confirmation when it's run by root.