# Deleting read-only directory on linux?

Tags: permissions, kali-linux, mkdir

I created an empty read-only directory:

```
mkdir -m 400 ~/Desktop/hello
```

As per the octal permission, it indicates the directory has read only permission.
But contrast to that when I am using the following command the directory was deleted:

```
rmdir ~/Desktop/hello
```

How is this possible to delete the directory when it is read only?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can rm remove read-only files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48579/why-can-rm-remove-read-only-files)

Comment: See also: [Execute vs Read bit. How do directory permissions in Linux work?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/21251/170373)